# Ubuntu Gnome crashes right after login

Tags: login, screen

Whenever I try to login on ubuntu gnome, it goes to black screen without being able to see anything. All I cand do is to press ctrl+alt+f login and acces the terminal. I'm so done after hundred of reboots and boots and so on, feels like I'm cursed...

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to fixed it! [This](https://jeremymdyson.wordpress.com/2016/04/27/ubuntugnome-16-04-on-asus-rog-gl552v/) was very helpful!

SOLUTION:

Once the login screen pop up, press `CTRL+ALT+F1/F2` (not sure which F key did the trick, try both) and a command line will appear asking you to login. After logging in, run the following command:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line that reads

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash”`

and change it to read

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0 tpm_tis.interrupts=0 acpi_osi=Linux i915.preliminary_hw_support=1 idle=nomwait”`

After you exit with `CTRL+X` and save it, make sure to update the grub with

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

And finally after everything was updated (to make sure the grub was updated, run the first command again to see the changes), reboot the computer and there you go! Ubuntu Gnone successfully installed!